# jquery checkbox click not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```
    <?php
    while($query=mysql_fetch_assoc($select)){
        ?>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxMail" id="checkBoxMail" 
        value="<?php echo $query['id']; ?>" 
        userid="<?php echo $query['suserid']; ?>"></td>

        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

This code created multiple checkbox in view page. First check only return value after that next check box click is not working

```
$('#checkBoxMail').click(function(){

    alert("alert");
});
```

Comment: You have to use `delegate` `event` binding. `$('#checkBoxMail').click` not works on dynamically created `html`. Have to do `$(document).on('click','.checkBoxMail', function(){
});`

Comment: you are using checkBoxMail as ID thats why for multiple same ID is not valid. For this you have to change ID to class='checkBoxMail' and  remove ID from input tag $('.checkBoxMail').click(function(){

    alert("alert");
});

Answer (score 6):

There would be multiple checkboxes with same `id` which is wrong. Try with `class`.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxMail" class="checkBoxMail" 
value="<?php echo $query['id']; ?>" 
userid="<?php echo $query['suserid']; ?>">
```

And

```
$('.checkBoxMail').click(function(){
    alert("alert");
});
```

And if you want to access the value or attribute then simple do -

```
$(this).val();
$(this).attr('userid');
```

Comment: you need to handle delegate cz checkbox geneated by loop depend on data

Comment: i highly doubt that your `.click` will work in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Three examples of how you can do this by ID:

Remember if you're creating multiple checkbox fields don't set the same ID, make a different ID for each one or you can select the checkbox by class by changing the `#` to `.` as you can use the classname multiple times.

**The ID has to be unique**

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  // By ID - ID has to be unique
  $('#checkBoxMail').on("click", function()
  {
    alert("alert");
  });
  
  $('#checkBoxMail2').click(function()
  {
    alert("alert2");
  });
  
  $(document).on("click", "#checkBoxMail3", function()
  {
    alert("alert3");
  });
  
  // By classname
  $('.checkBoxMail5').on("click", function()
  {
    alert("alert");
  });
  
  $('.checkBoxMail5').click(function()
  {
    alert("alert2");
  });
  
  $(document).on("click", ".checkBoxMail5", function()
  {
    alert("alert3");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Divs with unique ID
<hr>
<div id="checkBoxMail">CLICK ME</div>
<div id="checkBoxMail2">CLICK ME</div>
<div id="checkBoxMail3">CLICK ME</div>


<br>
Div with classname
<hr>
<div class="checkBoxMail5">CLICK ME</div>
```

Comment: id must be unqiue . you can't work with same id mutiple time . that is dynamic dom so it'll need delegate your first two way won't work .

Comment: But op need click on checkbox not in entire table

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi - I've changed my answer to say about ID's

Answer (score 0):

You are using same id for all checkbox creted, either use unique id for each checkbox or use class. See below code, where i have used class

```
<?php
    while($query=mysql_fetch_assoc($select)){
        ?>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxMail" class="checkBoxMail" 
        value="<?php echo $query['id']; ?>" 
        userid="<?php echo $query['suserid']; ?>"></td>

        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','.checkBoxMail', function(){
   alert("alert");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give class to all and Read about delegated event handlers , that would help: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on("click",".classname",function(event){
     alert("hi");
 });
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#checkBoxMail').is(':checked'){
    alert("alert");
});
```

Try this. Enjoy!

Comment: That's incomplete (it's only part of a conditional) and invalid javascript.

Comment: or he can use `document.getElementById('checkBoxMail').checked`  It will work too.

Comment: That's half a conditional and half a callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#checkBoxMail').click(function () {

    alert("click event fired")});

});

<input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxMail" id="checkBoxMail" />
```